# Application slows down when I upload an image

Tags: android

I am trying to upload an image in imageview on the profile fragment. I can upload the image succesfully, but then application very slows down. This is my code:

```
    private void checkAndRequestForPermission() {
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_FILE);
    }
    else{
        openGallery();
    }
}


private void openGallery() {

    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, 1);

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode ==1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!=null && data.getData() !=null) {
        getProfilePictureUri = data.getData();
        profile_picture.setImageURI(getProfilePictureUri);
    }
}
```

Should I change Uri to Bitmap? Thank you for your help.

Edit: I want to upload high resolution images, If I reduce the size, won't the resolution decrease?

Comment: Do you mean you get a message from the operating system saying your app is unresponsive?

Comment: @DavidChristopherReynolds No, the app works, but after uploading the photo fragment becomes very slow. Probably image size. I am not getting an error message.

Comment: Are you displaying the image in a list view or on its own?

Comment: @DavidChristopherReynolds On its own.

Comment: Strange. It shouldn't make that much of a difference then.